# Access 2013 VBA - new records from INSERT INTO not found by subsequent SELECT query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am updating an Access 2013 table through VBA. My task requires certain records to be added to the table during a loop and subsequently records to be read from the (updated) table. I am finding that my code works as expected provided I run through the code line by line in debug mode. However, if I run the code using F5, my results will be unpredictable. Sometimes the code works as expected and other times the loop finishes early. It looks as though the newly added records are not found by a select query, even though they have been added to the table. Referring to the code below, the INSERT INTO statement at the bottom is executed, but the subsequent opening of the adrsb recordset sometimes does not find the updated records, causing the loop to terminate early. I've been stumped on this for days now despite my best efforts in debugging. Any help will be very gratefully received. :)

```
Do
i = i + 1
'Debug.Assert i <> 4

If adrsb.State = 1 Then
    adrsb.Close
    Set adrsb = Nothing
    Set adrsb = New ADODB.Recordset
    adrsb.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    adrsb.CursorType = adOpenStatic
End If

'adrsb.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
adrsb.Open "SELECT tblInScopeRestructures.Code1, tblInScopeRestructures.Gen " & _
"FROM tblInScopeRestructures " & _
"GROUP BY tblInScopeRestructures.Code1, tblInScopeRestructures.Gen " & _
"HAVING (((tblInScopeRestructures.Gen)=" & i & "))" & _
"ORDER BY tblInScopeRestructures.Code1;"
adrsb.Requery

Dim adrsc As ADODB.Recordset

Set adrsc = New ADODB.Recordset
adrsc.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
adrsc.CursorType = adOpenStatic

If Not adrsb.EOF Then
    adrsb.MoveLast
    adrsb.MoveFirst
End If

If adrsb.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    adrsb.MoveFirst
    'strPrevCode1 = adrsb.Fields("Code1")

    Do While Not adrsb.EOF

    strPrevCode1 = adrsb.Fields("Code1")
        If adrsc.State = 1 Then
            adrsc.Close
        End If
        adrsc.CursorType = adOpenStatic
        adrsc.Open "SELECT tblRestructure.Code1, tblRestructure.Code2, tblRestructure.RecDate " & _
        "FROM tblRestructure " & _
        "WHERE (((tblRestructure.Code2)='" & strPrevCode1 & "'));"
        If adrsc.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        adrsc.MoveFirst
        Do While Not adrsc.EOF
       adConn.Execute ("INSERT INTO tblInScopeRestructures(Code1,Code2,RecDate,Gen) VALUES ('" & adrsc.Fields("Code1") & "','" & adrsc.Fields("Code2") & _
       "',#" & Format(adrsc.Fields("RecDate"), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#," & i + 1 & ")")
       Debug.Print adrsc.Fields("Code1") & adrsc.Fields("Code2")
       Debug.Print i + 1

       For j = 1 To 100000
       Next j

       adrsc.MoveNext

        Loop

       End If

      adrsb.MoveNext

      If adrsc.State = 1 Then
           adrsc.Close
      End If

    Loop

End If

   Debug.Assert adrsb.RecordCount <> 0
Loop While adrsb.RecordCount <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the problem is probably here

```
   adrsb.CursorType = adOpenStatic
```

change it to

```
   adrsb.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
```

And Instead of this bit of code:

```
   For j = 1 To 100000
   Next j
```

You could try something slightly less thrashy such as:

```
   DoEvents
```

And maybe after the DoEvents command, you could try adding a Requery command on your ADODB recordset.

Except you will probably lose your desired cursor position, so before doing the Refresh, you can record the ID of your primary key in a variable and then find that cursor location in the recordset

```
    intID = adrsb.Fields("MyKey")
    adrsb.Requery
    rs.Find "MyKey = " & intID
```

Comment: thanks - i'll try the stuff you mention. I had earlier experimented with the adOpenDynamic cursortype but it gave me other problems (from memory recordcount often showed as -1). The for-next loop in my code was a desperate hack to try and give time for the inserted records to be found by the subsequent select query, I meant to delete it before posting. i'll read up on DoEvents

Comment: Hi - I tried Mike's suggestions re the cursor type and using DoEvents but could not get a fix.

Comment: I now have a solution of sorts by adding the following pause code immediately after the EXECUTE INTO using the adrsc fields:
          'TWait = Time
           TWait = DateAdd("s", 5, TWait)
           Do Until TNow >= TWait
            TNow = Time
           Loop'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got a solution of sorts. I inserted the following code to cause a pause immediately after the second EXECUTE INTO operation:

```
       TWait = Time
       TWait = DateAdd("s", 5, TWait)
       Do Until TNow >= TWait
          TNow = Time
       Loop
```

This slows the code down very significantly, but it works. I experimented with shorter pauses but tended to get the same problems with the loop sometime exiting early. While the immediate problem is solved, I'm left a bit stunned that this is necessary and am worried about when such an issue will next raise its head.